# notepad++ don't show the right character despite the right encoding

Tags: notepad++, unicode, utf-8

My UTF8.txt file display all other Unicode characters fine but not the x̄, it show instead a"x" and it's top dash "-"on the right (and not above the x).

(When I copy past this x- from np++ to chrome or another app, it displays the right characters)

Any idea how to force np++ to shows it right?

Comment: Might be worth trying a different font. Arial Unicode maybe?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks! If you write it as an answer I could vote for it: setting /style configurator/ change the font name and check the box enable global font x̄

Comment: That seems a little more involved than my wild guess. Why not post it yourself, with some screenshots? I've got plenty of rep, and while I pointed you at the right direction, you seem to have found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This character was not included in the font I used. So changing the font solved it.

setting /style configurator/ change the font name and check the box enable global font.

Thanks to Journeyman Geek!